# Way to do a recursive chown avoiding any SELinux violation

Tags: android, selinux, chown

in script a.sh:

`chown -R root:group parent-folder/`

`chown -R root:group parent-folder/*`

The script runs as root user.

When chown gets executed it show below SELinux violations:

> chown   : type=1400 audit(0.0:7): avc: denied { dac_override } for capability=1 scontext=u:r:scriptName:s0 tcontext=u:r:scriptName:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1

What do I need to do to avoid the above dac_override ?
(I dont want to apply the dac_override SE policy of course)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the process with user/group which has required DAC permissions to access and modify the files. The process can not not change owner of the file without `CAP_CHOWN` capability. File owner can change the group to another group which the process is member of. Recursive `chown` also needs to have (at least) search permission to the directory in question.

For more details, see the man pages [`chown(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lchown.2.html) and [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Comment: required DAC permissions to access and modify the files ->
The runing process is part of the group , should the group have 7 or 5 ?

It is android world, so I made the process root user.
Is there anything else I am missing ?